# Can I show data linked to a shape in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a heatmap in Excel by cutting up all national regions in differend freeforms (forming the entire map of the country) to showcase different KPI's per region.

I'm trying to make this more interactive, so users can select a certain form (i.e. region) and return the data of this region (the specific KPI) in a cell.

What's the best possible option to get this done?

Comment: You can add an onclick event to each shape... but i understand that this might be very tedious. How many shapes are you looking at?

Comment: Quite a lot. - 282 shapes. I've got a list of freeform names (generic freeform no. per specific region) on which I based a VBA to give each shape a specific color based on the data.

Comment: @rohrl77 it wouln't be very tedious I think. You could name all shapes logically, e.g. 1-282. And assign them all the same macro that will pull the shape name and return data according to that shape name.

Comment: @JvdV I think that is a good proposal! Another idea is to work something out with the `SelectionChange` event of the worksheet... though i'm not certain if you can catch selected objects with that.

Comment: @rohrl77 That's a good idea. I'll see if I can use Application.Caller for that

Comment: Nevermind... SelectionChange is always a Range Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simplified example of what I meant in my previous comment:

[image]

- I have created 4 shapes and assigned them names `Shape_1` till `Shape_4`
- I made some worksheet code making use of `Application.Caller`

  ```
  Sub Test()

  Dim ShapeName As String, Rw() As String

  ShapeName = Application.Caller
  If InStr(1, ShapeName, "Shape_") > 0 Then
      Rw = Split(ShapeName, "_")
      MsgBox "This shape belongs to " & Range("A" & Rw(1))
  End If

  End Sub
  ```
- I assigned this macro to all 4 shapes
- Now you can click any of these shapes, for example, shape with the number 2:

[image]

You could even (not sure if handy) make the `KPI` part of the name of the shape and return that into a cell with `Rw(nth)`.

Obviously you can create a whole different approach with `Application.Caller`. You could for example search a substring of the shape in a matrix and return another value for example.